# Crystal Reports Count Records Between Two Parameter Dates

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Hopefully the title says it all.. But just in case. I am in the midst of reworking some custom-built in-house software, written in vb.net, that queries the database, gathers the returned data and processes it within the vb.net, then outputs the results to Crystal Reports to display.

We have found this to be incredibility wasteful of resources, and cruelly slow. Like I mentioned before I am reworking this program so that the Crystal Report itself gathers the information and displays it. This morning I am reworking a seemingly simple portion, a Monthly Report that just counts the total records, sums somethings and other small tasks.

So my question is this, what is the crystal syntax to count the number of records that is returned, that is between two dates.(parameters that are passed in from the vb side)

I want to write this:

```
COUNT({Table.Column} in {?FromDate} to {?ToDate});
```

Crystal Reports then highlights everything inside the count and tells me a field is required here.

I also tried to create a running total, but it only tallied 1. So if that is the correct course of action please explain.

Thanks!!

Comment: Will the report solely consist of records that fall in that date range? Or are those parameters not used in the record selection formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal reports formula syntax does not allow for a conditional count in this way. I usually perform this sort of thing with two separate formulas: The first populates 1 or 0 for the logic test, the second sums the first, e.g.

{@InRange}:

`if {Table.Column} in {?FromDate} to {?ToDate} then 1 else 0`

{@sumInRange}:

`sum({@InRange}`

I'm pretty sure I've achieved similar results in a single formula, but it makes the code less readable and harder to maintain, sometimes requiring `While Printing` commands that make the formula results inaccessible for use in other areas of the report. Using two formulas also allows for easy filtering on this first one.

Comment: +1 Alternatively, you can forgo the second formula, like you say, in favor of inserting the summary object into the report directly. The `WhilePrintingRecords` keyword is unnecessary when using plain old summary functions like `sum()` and `count()`.

Comment: I think this answer is brilliant. I haven't marked it as the answer yet because I am coming up with +10 when compared to the original. I am working this out and will return my findings.

Comment: Ha! Your answer produced the correct results. Had to dig a little deeper, but I found out that the previous vb.net code would not include the current date in the final results. Crystal Reports however was smart enough to add 1 millisecond to the datetime portion of the query, as to include the current date as well.

Comment: However, following the format of your answer I was able to produce a more readable code for me. I put `{table.column} in {?FromDate} to {?ToDate}` in {@InRange} then used `count({@InRange})` in {@sumInRange}